# wso2 esb json post method blank query parameter handling

Tags: json, rest, soap, wso2, esb

I converted JSON (client) to SOAP (back end) through ESB Proxy Service and it is working fine.

URL "https://someurl.com/json/"

The problem is that I am trying to call from another batch process application (Mirth) and it is adding "?" end of the URL changing the URL to "https://someurl.com/json?" How can I get rid of the "?" character?

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://wso2.org/library/knowledge-base/2011/01/custom-urls-wso2-esb-proxy-services) contains information on how to customize URLs.

This is also possible using [Script mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB403/Script+Mediator) - these can also be used for URL transformations.